# Transfering files from a server to a folder in another server with php

Tags: php

This is what i want,to place the file "change.php" into a folder on the clients server(clientserver.com/testfolder). I was able to move the file "change.php" from one server to the other online(myserver.com to clientserver.com).  Here is what i have try but can't have the results i want

```
<?php
/* Source File Name and Path */
    $remote_file = 'change.php';

/* FTP Account */
    $ftp_host = 'clientserver.com'; /* host */
    $ftp_user_name = 'username@clientserver.com'; /* username */
    $ftp_user_pass = 'password'; /* password */

/* Connect using basic FTP */
    $connect_it = ftp_connect( $ftp_host );

/* Login to FTP */
    $login_result = ftp_login( $connect_it, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass );

/* New file name and path for this file */
    $dst_dir = 'testfolder/';
    $local_file = 'testfolder/change.php';

// turn passive mode on
    ftp_pasv($connect_it, true);

// try to creat path
    ftp_chdir($connect_it, $dst_dir);

/* Download $remote_file and save to $local_file */
    if ( ftp_put( $connect_it, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY ) ){
        echo "WOOT! Successfully written to $local_file\n";
    } else {
        echo "Doh! There was a problem\n";
    }

/* Close the connection */
    ftp_close( $connect_it );
```

?>

Comment: can you remove the single quote? Try it and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Change `ftp_chdir($connect_it, '$dst_dir');` to this:

```
ftp_chdir($connect_it, $dst_dir);
```

The problem is that PHP does not replace variables in single-quoted strings.

```
$var = 'BUH';
echo 'Foo $var Bar';
echo "Foo $bar Bar";
```

will result in this output:

```
Foo $var Bar
Foo BUH Bar
```

Comment: Replace it with what

Comment: okay thanks , done that but i am having this warning "Warning: ftp_put(testfolder/change.php) [function.ftp-put]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/yemsgro/public_html/transload/transload.php on line 32" Doh! There was a problem"

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
ftp_chdir($connect_it, '$dst_dir'); to ftp_chdir($connect_it, $dst_dir);
```

Comment: i have change and try, this is the problem im facing now     "Warning: ftp_put(testfolder/change.php) [function.ftp-put]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/yemsgro/public_html/transload/transload.php on line 32"
Doh! There was a problem

Comment: are you sure the 'testfolder' already exist before you change the directory using ftp_chdir ??
you can use ftp_mkdir to created 'testfolder' on your destination server. ex : ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $dst_dir);

Comment: Yeah, i have the 'testfolder' on the destination server. i have try creating a directory but have the same warning. the folder is been created on the clientserver.com, my problem is moving the file to that directory